# spring 4 security jars are missing for offline download

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-4

while working on spring mvc 4, how to find the jar for offline project like the jar `Spring Security Config`,`spring-security-web` for spring 4 ... etc as thet are not available with default package of jars and I do not want to use maven at this time so where one can find the jar for spring 4
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, foregoing proper dependency management is a bad idea and will make development that much harder, especially when it comes to transitive dependency resolving.

However, if you really want to do it then you can download `.jar`s straight from [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/) or any other online repo that hosts them.
If that fails then a Google search will give you some source to download them from.

Comment: thanks for the reply and i am not getting any jar from zip that maven is providing and google search is giving me `spring3 security` jars

Comment: Well, I doubt you would find a comprehensive archive with all the related/required dependencies. It's possible but don't count on it as people are smart enough to use proper dep. management.

You can get the latest `spring-security-core` from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/4.1.3.RELEASE), click "Download (JAR)" and then look at the list under "Compile Dependencies" and download everything from there, too, one-by-one. This is the kind of work you're setting yourself up to do if you don't want to use Maven/Gradle/whatever.

Comment: i really appreciate that you provided that link but my question is how i can get jar or how to convert that zip file to jar or i should copy it to build path because I am writing code offline so I cannot get update everytime

Comment: Like I said, you can download the `.jar` library directly from that link. Add it to your build path with all the other dependencies listed there and you're good to go. There are no `.zip` files anywhere.

Comment: ok this is the file I am getting `spring-security-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.zip` when I click on download and when i extract it I am getting no jar. did you try?

Comment: You're getting a `.zip` because you're renaming the file when downloading. Keep the extension as `.jar` and it will work.

Comment: thanks i don't know why it is still downloading it as `zip` format  and I need to convert it into `jar` manually I should have thought that :)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to avoid a dependency management tool that to with a framework like Spring which complements many other frameworks is a bad idea in the long run. It will be painful to upgrade the versions in future.

But if you still don't want to use maven/gradle kind of build tool, just use pom.xml/build.gradle just for onetime use and let maven/gradle download all the dependencies and copy all those jars in some folder of your code.

Again I strongly suggest to use a build tool, especially for Spring. Maven/Gradle are not that bad if you don't want to do crazy things!!